# What is the difference between these two questions?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

Consider two independent random variables: X~U(0,1) and Y~U(0,2). Let Z = min(X,Y).
b) Find F$_Z$(z) in terms of F$_X$(.) and F$_Y$(.).
c) Eliminate F$_X$(.) and F$_Y$(.) to find F$_Z$(z).

What is the difference between these two questions when (from what I can tell) they're both finding the cumulative distribution function of the same thing? What does it mean by eliminate?

Our lecture notes don't contain any examples and I can't find anything on Google. Can anyone please demonstrate how to solve these seemingly identical(?) questions?

I can find the c.d.f of Z by finding 1 - F$_Z$ using P(Z > z), but I'm not sure which question this method falls under. I'm not even sure if there is another method.

Thanks

Comment: Where is option $a)$?

Comment: @exploringnet Question a) was just finding the cdf of X and Y which was easy enough.

Comment: Here's what I think: b) tells u to express $F_Z$ in terms of $F_X$ and $F_Y$. c) tells you to use that you know what the CDF of $X$ and $Y$ are, and plug in the expressions for $F_X$ and $F_Y$ in the expression for $F_Z$ obtained in b) - thus eliminating $F_X$ and $F_Y$.

Comment: @StefanHansen Thank you. That makes sense now.